# How do I fix this Jekyll Error in GitHub pages?

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I'm trying to get my website up and running through GitHub Pages and I'm having trouble.

On the page below, I had everything set up and I hit save:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW7Ya.png)

Next thing you know I received an email that explained that the build failed due to the following error:

Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error while converting 'assets/css/style.scss':
No such file or directory @ dir_chdir - /github/workspace/docs

Now when I try to click save again, nothing happens. I've tried refreshing the page, restarting the browser, and restarting my computer. It's as if the save button is greyed out (greyed out as in "I can't click it". The button is not actually greyed out.). So even if I'm able to figure out the Jekyll error, I'm not even sure it will matter because the save button doesn't seem to be doing anything.

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: You are attempting to configure Github pages to serve the pages in your `/docs` folder. Does your repo actually have a `/docs` folder?